# Keep session after browser closed

Tags: php, session, opencart

Hi all I have a following session code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['product_viewed'][$product_id])){
                $_SESSION['product_viewed'][$product_id] = $product_id;

            }
```

I tryed to set cookie with a similar name as session but got the sintax error. What I did wrong?

Comment: How you expect us to tell you where you went wrong without you posting the cookie code?

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are destroyed when the browser is closed.

The only way to achieve what you are trying to do is to insert the session data into a database as you go, effectively keeping two copies of it - and storing a key or unique ID in a cookie. When the user logs in again, the ID is taken from the cookie (or from another database table) and then a bit of code is run so that the data is fetched from the database. Once you have the data, you re-create the session for the user.

Cookies often have a 4k limit on what they can store, so if it is anything substantial, you won't be able to use them for what you want anyhow.

Having said all that, please do actually post some code so that we can see what you are trying to do to perhaps pinpoint the bit where you went wrong.

Without any real code in your question, I can only assume that you aren't doing any of this. If you show what you are actually doing, the users of SO can actually jump in and start to pinpoint where you are going wrong.